# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress

Tags: django, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am using `helm upgrade xyz --install` command and my release were failing due to other helm issues. So no successful release is done yet.

Then one time when the above command was in progress, I pressed `ctrl+c` command. And since then it is showing `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress` whenever I try `helm upgrade again`.

When i do helm history `helm history xyz` It shows `Error: release: not found`. No I don't know how to roll back the previous operation so that I can try helm upgrade again.

I tried --force too `helm upgrade xyz --install --force` but it is still showing `some operation is in progress.`

So how can I roll back the previous process when I don't have any successful release.

Comment: try 'helm uninstall xyz' and then upgrade --install again. if im not mistaken that should solve your problem

Comment: Getting `release: not found`

Comment: Delete it manually, with `kubectl delete`

Comment: delete is the alias of uninstall

Comment: kubectl delete, not helm delete

Comment: @Matt Found the issue. I was not giving namespace in helm delete command so It was using some default namespace. once i passed namespace it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use `helm rollback` to restore your previous revision:

```
helm rollback <name> <revision>
```

Comment: It was the first release, so previous revision was not there

Answer (score 2):

your previously installed/ upgraded helms are in the status of pending-upgrade. These charts were not shown, when we list the helms. try using helm status [chart_name], it shows the current state of charts. uninstall the charts for which the status : pending.
Then you can reinstall the charts without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> Found the issue.
>
> I was not giving namespace in helm delete command so It was using some default namespace. once i passed namespace it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
helm -n namespace history myapp
helm -n namespace rollback 7
```

Here 7 is just the revision to which i rolled back. After this you can proceed with your regular upgrade

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to get the status of that release using

```
helm status <release-name>
```

Then I saw that the status for that release is `pending-upgrade`. I simply uninstalled that release using

```
helm uninstall <release-name>
```

and ran the install command again.